# how to paint on sculpts without retopo for idealization?

Tags: texturing, texture-painting, sculpting, vertex-paint, sculpt

I am trying paint in eye brows and eye shadow without having to retopo because  I just want to see the idealization of the model/sculpt. Is this possible or maybe there is a better way to do this that im not thinking about any advice would be awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to do any texturing, you can use vertex paint. It's like painting on the surface of your 3D model. It's not the most advisable method of coloring, texturing usually is, but if you don't want to have to deal with retopo and just want an idea of what your colors are going to be, vertex painting is an great tool. I'm not that great at teaching, but I do have a video that might help:

[Vertex Paint Workflow in Blender 2.8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HDWSkCDIu1E)

Hope I somewhat answered your question :)

Comment: Wow  you went far above my expectations this is amazing! thank you so much! A real quick question about this mode is can you have a soft brush like the one for masking sculpt and how do you erase in this mode?

Comment: I think the brush is soft by default. The subtract brush is one way you can erase, but you can also use your secondary color (press ctrl to use your secondary color) if it is set to the color to match your base color. there aren't a lot of tools though, and I find the subtract brush to be a bit convoluted. And obtuse. Sorry for taking so long to respond, I was trying to figure out vertex painting for myself -_-

Comment: haha its no problem but thank you for the help! Do you have a discord?